# How to make a rigged/animated object flop on the ground using gravity.

Tags: rigging, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to make a rigged worm object that's been animated flop on the ground. Instead of animating it flopping around on the ground, I figured I'd just animate the squirm movement and make it an active object that interacts with a passive floor and let gravity do the rest to make it more realistic. Problem is, I cannot figure out how to make able to freely move about with gravity without the whole rig either wigging out or it just not moving. Is there a tutorial for this kind of thing because I can't find one. A little help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: "flopping around on the ground" don't really describe the motion you are after... it would be helpful if you have an object flopping in a youtube video or example so other understand what you are aiming for.

Comment: This isn't going to work! (I just tried it.)  The worm movement whivh elevates most of its body pushes it up much to easily, since it has infinite strength. Adding realistic gravity to the weightless motion makes it look really bad. Movements, which create potential wnergy by raising the worm would be much slower than the worms body falling back onto the ground. You can take this into account by animating it in space.

Comment: Ok so in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=33&v=BGYIca88A4s at 0:28 when they fall to the ground and start moving around, this is the same kind of effect I'm talking about. The creatures are rigged and animated but are still affected by gravity.